# How to add items to recyclerView in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want add some list from server into my `recyclerView`.
My list items size has 10, but i want **add last 7 item** to this RecyclerView. I **don't want add first 3 item** to this `recyclerView`

**I write below code :**

```
        Call<ListCartResponse> call = apIs.getListCardResponse(jwtToken);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListCartResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ListCartResponse> call, Response<ListCartResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {

                                if (response.body().getRes().getCarts() != null) {
                                    if (response.body().getRes().getCarts().size() > 0) {
                                        model.clear();
                                        model.addAll(response.body().getRes().getCarts());
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ListCartResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
```

But in my above codes add all of 10 items to `recyclerView`.
I want add just last 7 items and remove 3 first items.

**My recyclerView items now** : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
**But i want** : 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

How can i it?

Comment: please post adapter code also.

Comment: @aminography, please see my update post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`subList()`** method of **`List`** interface:

For your example :

```
model.clear();
model.addAll(response.body().getRes().getCarts().subList(3, 9));
```

*Note: Beware that if your list from server is less than 10 items and you still need last 7 items, then you should pass index dynamically instead (Above solution will crash for that instance)*

[**Reference**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))

> **subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)**
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   `fromIndex`, inclusive, and `toIndex`, exclusive. (If `fromIndex` and
>   `toIndex` are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is
>   backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
>
> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the
>   sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a
>   list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view
>   instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a
>   range of elements from a list:
>
> ```
> list.subList(from, to).clear();
> ```
>
> Similar idioms may be constructed for `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`,
>   and all of the algorithms in the **`Collections`** class can be
>   applied to a subList.
>
> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if
>   the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way
>   other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a
>   fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> *fromIndex* - low endpoint (inclusive) of the subList
>
> *toIndex* - high endpoint (exclusive) of the subList
>
> **Returns:**
>
> a view of the specified range within this list

Comment: Thanks my dear friend for you great help <3

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
   if (response.body().getRes().getCarts().size() > 0) 
    {
      model.clear();
      model.addAll(response.body().getRes().getCarts());
      model.remove(0);
      model.remove(0);
      model.remove(0);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();        
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the `model` in response part does not refer to `model` in your adapter class. Add this to your `SupportListAdapter` class, the use it when response has received:

```
public void replaceModelList(List<Res> newModel){
     model.clear();
     model.addAll(newModel);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When result has received:

```
if (response.body().getRes().getCarts() != null) {
     if (response.body().getRes().getCarts().size() > 0)
          adapter.replaceModelList(response.body().getRes().getCarts());
```